# how to save javascript variable to my sql by using spring boot controller?

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I need to store `email_id` to my sql using spring boot. How do I send this variable to controller without using submit-form action?

```
function testAPI() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', {
      locale: 'en_US',
      fields: 'name, email'
    },
    function(response) {
      var email_id = response.email;
      //      }
      //FB.api('/me', function(response)
      //    {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + 'thats it');
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging , ' + email_id + '!';
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing? What kind of technologies are you using?

Comment: @Albert        HTML, JS, Spring Boot MySQL, I am trying to retrieve my email id by using facebook api and store it in database

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('key', 'value');

function yourAjaxFunction() {
      var ajaxCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajaxCall.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Printing the response here");
            console.log(this);
        }
      };
      ajaxCall.open("GET", "Your full url here", true);
      ajaxCall.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I have tried to populate a new html form. anyways thanks for the help